# Dynamic Method Calls

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

From what I understand, methods can be dynamically called if **both the method name and list of parameter types** are provided (see below). However, is there a way to dynamically call a method *without* specifying parameter types or alternatively providing un/bounded generic class types? If yes, explanations/examples would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Class<?>[] paramTypes = {String.class};
Method m = original.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
m.invoke(original, value);
```

Comment: You can get all declared methods with `getDeclaredMethods`, but if you don't know the arguments to provide (do you?), how will you invoke the method?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: the OP knows the *values*, so its possible to determine the argument types but that’s an additional operation. Further, the *argument* types are not necessarily the *parameter* types, e.g. your argument might be a `String` but the target method may accept any `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution since Java 1.4, [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Statement.html) and [`Expression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Expression.html) of the beans package. For your invocation, not evaluating return values, you can use

```
new Statement(original, methodName, new Object[]{value}).execute();
```

Since it has to figure out even more than the direct Reflection usage, you can expect the performance to be even worse than directly using Reflection.

Further, it is restricted to `public` APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically lookup the target method based on a target, a name and available argument types then the [MethodHandle machinery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#findVirtual-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) might prove useful.